# form_for checkboxes only working on the first jquery-tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, loops, checkbox, jquery-tabs

I'm creating a `form_for` that basically lets the user mark when it has completed a video. I'm nesting this form inside a jQuery tabs and want to have one checkbox on each tab, and so far I got that. However the functionality is the one that is failing: Only the checkbox on the first tab actually changes the value when it is submitted. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
<% for i in 1..@statement %>
<div id="htab-current-<%= i %>">
  <%= form_for @user.workouts.where(week_num:  @week).where(video_num_in_week: i).first.assignedworkouts.first, remote:true ,:html=>{:id=>'completed_form'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.check_box :completed, :onclick => "$('#completed_form').submit()" %>      
  <% end %>

  <div class='videowrapper2'>
    <div id="myElement<%= i %>">Loading the player ...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jwplayer("myElement<%= i %>").setup({
        skin: 'five',
        width: "100%",
        aspectratio: "4:3",
        listbar: {
          position: 'bottom',               
        },
        playlist: '<%=asset_path(@user.workouts.where(week_num:  @week).where(video_num_in_week: i).first.playlist_file ) %>'
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I tried brute forcing it and actually it was an issue of the id on the form being the same. However when I changed it to be generated dynamically even though the ids on the form and the jQuery call are the same, they don't seem to be working.

```
<% for i in 1..@statement %>
<div id="htab-current-<%= i %>">
  <%= form_for @user.workouts.where(week_num:  @week).where(video_num_in_week: i).first.assignedworkouts.first, remote:true ,:html=>{:id=>"#{i}completed_form'"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.check_box :completed, :onclick => "$('#{i}completed_form').submit()" %>

    <% end %>
  <div class='videowrapper2'>
    <div id="myElement<%= i %>">Loading the player ...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jwplayer("myElement<%= i %>").setup({
        skin: 'five',
        width: "100%",
        aspectratio: "4:3",
        listbar: {
          position: 'bottom',               
        },
        playlist: '<%=asset_path(@user.workouts.where(week_num:  @week).where(video_num_in_week: i).first.playlist_file ) %>'
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will generate one form per workout and you can only submit one form at a time. Try a different approach where it is all in a single form.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
<% for i in 1..@statement %>
<div id="htab-current-<%= i %>">
  <%= form_for @user.workouts.where(week_num:  @week).where(video_num_in_week: i).first.assignedworkouts.first, remote:true ,:html=>{:id=>'completed_form'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.check_box :completed, :onclick => "$('#completed_form').submit()" %>

  <div class="videowrapper2">
    <div id="myElement<%= i %>">Loading the player ...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jwplayer("myElement<%= i %>").setup({
        skin: 'five',
        width: "100%",
        aspectratio: "4:3",
        listbar: {
          position: 'bottom',               
        },
        playlist: '<%=asset_path(@user.workouts.where(week_num:  @week).where(video_num_in_week: i).first.playlist_file ) %>'
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: This one marks me that theres an end statement missing. Probably since you removed the one that coses the form. I have the double end one for closing the loop and one for the form, but thanks for your answer. I think the trouble is actually that all the forms are being generated with the same html id